# overflow-x: auto cause extra space below?

Tags: css, touch

Look this! there is a red upper white space when "overflow-x: auto;" be activated. How to remove this space and still slide across the view on the mobile?

HTML

```
<div class="content">
<ul class="crumb no-scrollbar">
<li>Home</li>
<li>Category1</li>  
<li>Category2</li>  
<li>Category3</li>
<li>Category4</li>
<li>Category5</li>
<li>Category6</li>
<li>Category7</li>
<li>Category8</li>
<li>Category9</li>
<li>Category9</li>
</ul>
<div class="desr">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.crumb {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.crumb li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.desr {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
.no-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 0;
}
.no-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    background:transparent
}
.no-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background:transparent
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nposqt8x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altered the `height` of scrollbar as shown below:

```
.no-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Works perfectly when overflow is applied.

[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/y93nLa60/)

Comment: Exactly. Your code helped me solve the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue by using : `overflow-x: auto;`

I fixed that by using : `overflow-x: clip;` instead.

It does the same thing (for me : remove the over scrolling) without the space below.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was the only way, everything else didn't worked: `margin-bottom: -4px;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).